# Need help solving highly non-linear coupled equations numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

For my master's project (mathematical modelling of cardiac cells) I need to solve a system of highly nonlinear equations numerically.

I've tried MATLAB, MAPLE, C++, even WolframAlpha and I'm at a total loss and beginning to panic.

Here is a link to the equations. https://i.stack.imgur.com/40M8l.jpg I'm really desperate.... please help!

**Please verify these - they are impossible to read with such a low quality image.**

Solve for the initial values $V_0, n_0, m_0$ and $h_0$ given by

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1} n_0 &= \dfrac{\alpha_{n_0}}{\alpha_{ n_0} + \beta_{n_0}} \\
\tag{2} m_0 &= \dfrac{\alpha_{m_0}}{\alpha_{ m_0} + \beta_{ m_0}} \\
\tag{3} h_0 &= \dfrac{\alpha_{ h_0}}{\alpha_{ h_0} + \beta_{ h_0}}  \\
\tag{4} V_0 &= \dfrac{I + \overline{g_K}~ n_0^4~ V_k + \overline{g_{N_a}}~ m_0^3 ~h_0~ V_{N_a} + g_l~ V_l}{\overline{g_K}~ n_0^4 + \overline{g_{N_a}}~ m_0^3~ h_0 +~ g_l}\end{align} $$

where

$$\begin{align}
\tag{5} \alpha_{n_0} &= \dfrac{0.01(10 - V_0)}{\large e^{\frac{10-V_0}{10}}-1 } \\
\tag{5} \beta_{n_0} &= \large \dfrac{0.125}{e^{\frac{V_0}{80}}} \\
\tag{6} \alpha_{m_0} &= \dfrac{0.01(25 - V_0)}{\large e^{\frac{25-V_0}{10}}-1 }\\
\tag{6} \beta_{m_0} &= \large \dfrac{4}{e^{\frac{V_0}{18}}} \\
\tag{7} \alpha_{h_0} &= \dfrac{0.07}{\large e^{\frac{V_0}{20}}}\\
\tag{7} \beta_{h_0} &= \large \dfrac{1}{e^{\frac{30-V_0}{10}}+1} \\
\end{align}$$

and $I, \overline{g_K}, \overline{g_{N_a}}, g_l, V_K, V_{N_a}, V_l$ are constants. Example values

$$\begin{align}
\tag{8} I &= 0.0 \\
\tag{9} \overline{g_K} &= 36.0 \\
\tag{10} \overline{ g_{N_a}} &= 120.0 \\
\tag{11} g_l &= 0.3 \\
\tag{12} V_K &= 12.0 \\
\tag{13} V_{N_a} &= 115.0 \\
\tag{14} V_l &= 10.6
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: You can help your readers by using mathjax for your formulas to display them. It's very close to LaTeX (which you seem to be using for your screenshot) and you might get by with actually pasting the whole LaTeX source (including your `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`) to get a visible result.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try? What do the vertical bars mean? In some equations you have what looks like 1 (one) in the denominator. Is that right?

Comment: can you post your System here please?

Comment: @JennieAstley: Please verify the edit I made because the master is awful quality and almost unreadable.